# how to intall .ipa file on Ipad simulator?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I'm newbie to ipad/iphone apps, I have a .ipa file which need to test using ipad simulator.
Can some one help me installing ipad app(.ipa) in on simulator.

I appreciate your help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  You can deploy builds to testers using ad-hoc deployment (or via TestFlight) to test on actual devices.  Testing in the simulator is done by building the source code in XCode.